Updated to jupyter7 but it gets stuck after running a few cells
Running in the new jupyter7 my notebooks developed on jupyter 6 brings tons of problems and I've been unable to work for several weeks. Major problem is that after running a few cells (sometimes 10 cells, other times 20 cells) it just gets stuck, sometimes after an error other times just like that, it does not run cells anymore, and cannot even restart the kernel:
"kernel" menu is blank except for "Shut down all kernels"
I am using an "old" (2017) iMAc with Ventura 13.6.6 and my life has been miserable (3 weeks) since Macports imposed the new jupyter 7 where nothing works
I uninstalled and reinstalled my full Macports system several times and can only bang my head against the wall
